# What is the best way to get a stacktrace when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm wondering about the best way to get a stacktrace when there is an exception inside a function executed via the multiprocessing module. Here's an example:

```
import multiprocessing

def square(x):
    raise Exception("Crash.")
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    results = pool.map_async(square, range(5))
    for result in results.get():
        print result
```

This prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/extra/workspace/Playground/src/multiproc/multiproc_debug.py", line 11, in <module>
    for result in results.get():
  File "/extra/Python 2.6/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 422, in get
    raise self._value
Exception: Crash.
```

So there is no useful stacktrace, which is quite annoying. My current solution for this:

```
import multiprocessing
import traceback

def square(x):
    try:
        # some more code...
        raise Exception("Crash.")
    except Exception, exception:
        print exception
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise
    return x**2
```

Is there a way to get this behaviour without all the boilerplate code? If not, what is the reason for not including this feature?

Edit: One could use a decorator for the boilerplate code, but I don't know if such a decorator is included in the standard library?

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you should avoid raising the exception from your main function.  Instead, you can catch it, treat it as a value returned to the main program, then raise it there.  [Re-throwing exceptions in Python](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200711/rethrowing_exceptions_in_python.html) has more details.

Comment: Unfortunately this part of the question is still open "Is there a way to get this behaviour without all the boilerplate code? " (For Python2.7, since 3.x includes fixes).

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.4, full traceback is provided.

http://bugs.python.org/issue13831

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2

I've made a decorator implementation as below. 
Note the usage of `functools.wraps`, otherwise the `multiprocessing` would fail.

```
def full_traceback(func):
    import traceback, functools
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            msg = "{}\n\nOriginal {}".format(e, traceback.format_exc())
            raise type(e)(msg)
    return wrapper
```

An example can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43223455.

### Python 3

As metioned by **Paige Lo**,now the `get` method of `multiprocessing.pool.Async` returns full traceback in Python 3, see http://bugs.python.org/issue13831.