# Python: Getting a traceback from a multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, exception, process, multiprocessing, traceback

I am trying to get hold of a traceback object from a multiprocessing.Process.
Unfortunately passing the exception info through a pipe does not work because traceback objects can not be pickled:

```
def foo(pipe_to_parent):
    try:
        raise Exception('xxx')
    except:
        pipe_to_parent.send(sys.exc_info())

to_child, to_self = multiprocessing.Pipe()
process = multiprocessing.Process(target = foo, args = (to_self,))
process.start()
exc_info = to_child.recv()
process.join()
print traceback.format_exception(*exc_info)
to_child.close()
to_self.close()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 231, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "foo", line 7, in foo
    to_parent.send(sys.exc_info())
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'traceback'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.traceback failed
```

Is there another way to access the exception info? I'd like to avoid passing the formatted string.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Using [`tblib`](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-tblib) you can pass wrapped exceptions and reraise them later:

```
import tblib.pickling_support
tblib.pickling_support.install()

from multiprocessing import Pool
import sys


class ExceptionWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, ee):
        self.ee = ee
        __, __, self.tb = sys.exc_info()

    def re_raise(self):
        raise self.ee.with_traceback(self.tb)
        # for Python 2 replace the previous line by:
        # raise self.ee, None, self.tb


# example of how to use ExceptionWrapper

def inverse(i):
    """ will fail for i == 0 """
    try:
        return 1.0 / i
    except Exception as e:
        return ExceptionWrapper(e)


def main():
    p = Pool(1)
    results = p.map(inverse, [0, 1, 2, 3])
    for result in results:
        if isinstance(result, ExceptionWrapper):
            result.re_raise()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So, if you catch an exception in your remote process, wrap it with `ExceptionWrapper` and then pass it back. Calling `re_raise()` in the main process will do the work.

Comment: I'm not sure why this hasn't been upvoted before. It works nicely for me! Maybe you should include an example of how to use `DelayedException`

Comment: I guess I was too late, or people do not see my ingenuity ;-)

Comment: This *is* ingenious! I just added som fixes to make it work and an example.

Comment: I take your point @rocksportrocker that my edit did not strictly match what the OP asked for. I added it as a separate answer, just for the record.

Comment: According to the docs, `tblib.pickling_support.install()` must be called AFTER the declaration of `ExceptionWrapper`, or as a decorator to the class definition. https://github.com/ionelmc/python-tblib#pickling-tracebacks

Comment: Depending on the use case, it may be possible to avoid the global side effect on the pickle machinery by using tblib's to_dict/from_dict instead: https://github.com/ionelmc/python-tblib#tblib-traceback-to-dict

Answer (score 30):

Since `multiprocessing` does print the string contents of exceptions raised in child processes, you can wrap all your child process code in a try-except that catches any exceptions, formats the relavent stack traces, and raises a new `Exception` that holds all the relevant information in its string:

An example of a function I use with `multiprocessing.map`:

```
def run_functor(functor):
    """
    Given a no-argument functor, run it and return its result. We can 
    use this with multiprocessing.map and map it over a list of job 
    functors to do them.

    Handles getting more than multiprocessing's pitiful exception output
    """

    try:
        # This is where you do your actual work
        return functor()
    except:
        # Put all exception text into an exception and raise that
        raise Exception("".join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())))
```

What you get is a stack trace with another formatted stack trace as the error message, which helps with debugging.

Comment: The OP specifically said he wanted to avoid passing a formatted string.

Answer (score 14):

It seems to be difficult to made picklable the traceback object.
But you can only send the 2 first items of `sys.exc_info()`, and a preformated traceback information with the [traceback.extract_tb](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_tb) method :

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
import traceback

def foo(pipe_to_parent):
    try:
        raise Exception('xxx')
    except:
        except_type, except_class, tb = sys.exc_info()
        pipe_to_parent.send((except_type, except_class, traceback.extract_tb(tb)))

to_child, to_self = multiprocessing.Pipe()
process = multiprocessing.Process(target = foo, args = (to_self,))
process.start()
exc_info = to_child.recv()
process.join()
print exc_info
to_child.close()
to_self.close()
```

which give you :

`(<type 'exceptions.Exception'>, Exception('xxx',), [('test_tb.py', 7, 'foo', "raise Exception('xxx')")])`

And then, you'll be able to grab more informations about the exception cause (filename, line number where exception raised, method name and the statement that raise the exception)

Comment: I used the exact same approach, but be aware that this will not work under python3, where you can get FrameSummary objects in traceback (instead of tuples). The FrameSummary objects are not JSON serializable (probably picklable however)

Answer (score 11):

### Python 3

In Python 3, now the `get` method of `multiprocessing.pool.Async` returns full traceback, see http://bugs.python.org/issue13831.

### Python 2

Use the `traceback.format_exc` (which means formatted expetion) to get the traceback string.
It would be much more covenient with making a decorator as below.

```
def full_traceback(func):
    import traceback, functools
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            msg = "{}\n\nOriginal {}".format(e, traceback.format_exc())
            raise type(e)(msg)
    return wrapper
```

Example:

```
def func0():
    raise NameError("func0 exception")

def func1():
    return func0()

# Key is here!
@full_traceback
def main(i):
    return func1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    pool = Pool(4)
    try:
        results = pool.map_async(main, range(5)).get(1e5)
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

The traceback *with* the decorator:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bt.py", line 34, in <module>
    results = pool.map_async(main, range(5)).get(1e5)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: Exception in func0

Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bt.py", line 13, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bt.py", line 27, in main
    return func1()
  File "bt.py", line 23, in func1
    return func0()
  File "bt.py", line 20, in func0
    raise NameError("Exception in func0")
NameError: Exception in func0
```

The traceback *without* the decorator:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bt.py", line 34, in <module>
    results = pool.map_async(main, range(5)).get(1e5)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: Exception in func0
```

Comment: However, the traceback outputs two extra lines due to the wrapper function. I think it's acceptable, right?

Answer (score 4):

This is a variation of [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26096355/512111). Both are relying on [tblib](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-tblib) for storing the traceback.

However, instead of having to return the exception object (as asked for by the OP), the `worker` function can be left as-is and is just wrapped in `try`/`except` to store exceptions for re-raise.

```
import tblib.pickling_support
tblib.pickling_support.install()

import sys

class DelayedException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, ee):
        self.ee = ee
        __,  __, self.tb = sys.exc_info()
        super(DelayedException, self).__init__(str(ee))

    def re_raise(self):
        raise self.ee, None, self.tb
```

### Example

```
def worker():
    try:
        raise ValueError('Something went wrong.')
    except Exception as e:
        raise DelayedException(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import multiprocessing

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    try:
        pool.imap(worker, [1, 2, 3])
    except DelayedException as e:
        e.re_raise()
```

Answer (score 0):

The same solutions as [@Syrtis Major](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43223455/4934640) and [@interfect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16618842/4934640) but, tested with Python 3.6:

```py
import sys
import traceback
import functools

def catch_remote_exceptions(wrapped_function):
    """ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126007/python-getting-a-traceback """

    @functools.wraps(wrapped_function)
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs)

        except:
            raise Exception( "".join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())) )

    return new_function
```

Usage:

```
class ProcessLocker(object):
    @catch_remote_exceptions
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @catch_remote_exceptions
    def create_process_locks(self, total_processes):
        self.process_locks = []
        # ...
```