# Avoid Subprocess Timeouts

Tags: python

Okay, so I'm currently using a python script to upload multiple files to a given server at once.

I'm running python version 2.7.3.

```
def upload(t):
    server="server"
    user="user"
    password="password"
    service="service"
    ftp=ftplib.FTP(server)
    ftp.login(user=user,passwd=password,acct="")
    ftp.storbinary("STOR "+t.split('/')[-1], open(t,"rb"))
    print "{} has been uploaded to {}".format(t.split("/")[-1],service)
def ftp_upload(t=files):
    server="server"
    user="user"
    password="password"
    service="service"
    ftp.login(user=user,passwd=password,acct="")
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(upload,t)
```

However, I am getting error messages as timeouts with sockets occur or something (which doesn't happen when I just use the ftp console command).

It seems like subprocess does something different?  I don't even particularly care about monitoring it; in fact, I'd rather the process not terminate if my connection to the server is messed with.  Any reporting is gravy.

Error Message:

```
 File "/usr/bin/jat", line 301, in ftp_upload
    pool.map(upload,files_to_upload)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Comment: What Python version do you use?

Comment: Sorry, didn't remember to put it in original post.  2.7.3

Comment: Please post the precise error message instead of `or something`. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, sometime it takes awhile before it comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pool.Map() propagates exceptions from the subprocesses it manages to the main process. Notice that the exceptions are being reported from multiprocessing/pool.py, and the traceback ends with "raise self._value".

That line indicates that the socket.timeout is being raised in one of the subprocesses. I suspect it's your ftp.login that is timing out. According to [the ftplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html), the global default timeout is used by an FTP object if you don't specify one when you create the object.

On a side note, I would suggest using one of the approaches suggested by the answerers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126007/python-getting-a-traceback-from-a-multiprocessing-process) to pass a bit more detail back to your main thread when an exception occurs in a subprocess.