# Multiprocessing with PyJack

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I'm building a compas, which is a particular flamenco metronome.
I want to direct the sound to Jack Audio. I'm using Python and PySide. So I'm using the PyJack library to process a wave file in jack:

```
def launchSoundThread(
    for sample in sampleWavs[sampleNumber]:
            try:
                compas_client.process(sample, input_samples)
            except jack.InputSyncError:
                print("InputSyncError")
            except jack.OutputSyncError:
                print("OutputSyncError")
```

My problem is, while processing the sound, the UI freezes. Threads don't help because of the Python Tiplock. So I'm trying to use multiprocessing and async functions:

```
pool = Pool(1)
r = pool.apply_async(launchSoundThread, args=() )
```

or

```
audio_process = Process( target=launchSoundThread, rgs=( ))
audio_process.start()
```

Neither of them work. They both get stuck while processing the audio and don't produce any sound.

Any suggestions?
Many Thanks in advance
Federico

Comment: Can you use a method similar the one [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16618842/2615940) to dump a traceback to a file and make sure there aren't any exceptions occurring in your subprocesses? The asynchronous multiprocessing methods won't necessarily dump exceptions to sterr or stdout for you to see.